# Shell script to check file name with two extension and if file with both the extension are present call a script otherwise it should fail

Tags: shell-script, files, find, directory

I need to check a file with two extensions (.txt and .ctl) in a directory and if file is present with both the extensions call a script.
If not the job should fail.
I tried some methods but it is not working as expected.
Can anyone  please help me.

Comment: You mean `[ -e /a/directory/file.txt.ctl ] || exit` ?

Comment: It's unclear if you want to test for the existence of file with `.txt` and `.ctl` filename suffixes (i.e. the existence of both `somefile.txt` and `otherfile.ctl`), or whether you want to test for the existence of a single file with _both_ filename suffixes (e.g. `somefile.ctl.txt` or `otherfile.txt.ctl`).

Comment: what methods did you try? ... how did they fail?

Comment: I want to check if somefile.txt and somefile.ctl both are present in a directory then the script should be called otherwise it should fail

Comment: With that clarification, then `[ -e somefile.txt  -a  -e somefile.ctl ] || exit 1`, like the first comment suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Assuming the directory is passed to us as an argument...
DIR="$1"
SCRIPT=/path/to/the/other/script.sh

COUNT=0
for i in "$DIR"/*.txt "$DIR"/*.ctl ;do
  if [ -f "$i" ] ;then # this is a regular file
    ((COUNT++))
    "$SCRIPT" "$i"
  fi
done

if [ $COUNT -eq 0 ] ;then
   exit 1 # No .txt or .ctl files were found.
fi
```

The question was not very clear, so I assumed that you want to check all files in a certain directory for either of those two extensions.

Comment: You may want to read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and [What's the purpose of adding a prefix on both sides of a shell variable comparison to a string literal?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/490393). That script has several bugs and arbitrary command injection vulnerabilities. Expansions must be quoted in bash and `-o` is deprecated and should not be used in arguments to `[`.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas: Redone. This should be better. :-)

Comment: That's better. You still have some unquoted parameter expansions though. Also `[ -f "$i" ]`  tests whether `$i` is a *regular* file to the exclusion of any other type of file. Everything is a file on Unix.

Comment: I shoud get rid of that [ -f "$i" ] test altogether. I mean, the more complex we make it, the harder it will be for the OP to explain her homework assignment. :-)) I only put it there to filter out possible files with weird chars in the name. Also, if one of the extensions is not found, in certain iteration of the loop there will be something that's not a file in the variable $i.  So yes, regular file to the exclusion of anything else.

Comment: Note that `[ -f "$i" ]` won't filter by name, only by type. If you don't want to discriminate by type, you can use `[ -e "$i" ]` instead. Or you could set the `nullglob` option and do away with the loop, just check that the glob generated some files.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me exactly what you're wanting to check. Here is to give you some avenues to solve your problem in the `zsh` shell:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

for dir do
  txt=($dir/*.txt(ND:t:r))
  ctl=($dir/*.ctl(ND:t:r))
  both=("${(@)txt:*ctl}")
  txt_but_not_ctl=("${(@)txt:|ctl}")
  ctl_but_not_txt=("${(@)ctl:|txt}")

  print -r -- "$dir has $#txt file${txt[2]+s} with a .txt extension"
  print -r -- "$dir has $#ctl file${ctl[2]+s} with a .ctl extension"
  print -r -- "$#both .txt file${both[2]+s} in $dir have matching files with the same root name and a .ctl extension"
  print -r -- "$dir has $#txt_but_not_ctl .txt file${txt_but_not_ctl[2]+s} without a corresponding .ctl file"
  print -r -- "$dir has $#ctl_but_not_txt .ctl file${ctl_but_not_txt[2]+s} without a corresponding .txt file"

  (($#both && $#txt_but_not_ctl == 0 && $#ctl_but_not_txt == 0)) &&
    print -r -- "all the .txt files in $dir have a corresponding .ctl file and vis versa"
done
```

The key constructs of interest here are:

- `files=(*(DN))`: assign the list of files matching a pattern to an array variable. `D` to include hidden ones, `N` to allow empty  lists (`nullglob`).
- `:t:r`, takes the *head* (remove the directory part), and *root* remove extension.
- `${A:*B}` intersection of two arrays. `"${(@)A:*B}"` preserves empty elements (like when there's a file called `.txt` or `.ctl`).
- `${A:|B}` subtraction of two arrays (elements of `A` that are not in `B`).
- `$#array`: number of elements in the array.
- `(( arithmetic expression ))` evaluates the arithmetic expression and returns *true* if the result is anything but 0.

If on a recent GNU-based system, you could do something approaching with `bash` (though a lot more awkwardly, painfully and less efficiently) with something like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

printz() {
  (($# == 0)) || printf '%s\0' "$@"
}

for dir do
  txt=("$dir"/*.txt)
  txt=("${txt[@]##*/}")
  txt=("${txt[@]%.*}")
  ctl=("$dir"/*.ctl)
  ctl=("${ctl[@]##*/}")
  ctl=("${ctl[@]%.*}")

  readarray -td '' both < <(
    LC_ALL=C comm -z12 <(printz "${txt[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort -z) \
                       <(printz "${ctl[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort -z))
  readarray -td '' txt_but_not_ctl < <(
    LC_ALL=C comm -z13 <(printz "${txt[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort -z) \
                       <(printz "${ctl[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort -z))
  readarray -td '' ctl_but_not_txt < <(
    LC_ALL=C comm -z23 <(printz "${txt[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort -z) \
                       <(printz "${ctl[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort -z))

  printf '%s\n' "$dir has ${#txt[@]} file${txt[2]+s} with a .txt extension"
  printf '%s\n' "$dir has ${#ctl[@]} file${ctl[2]+s} with a .ctl extension"
  printf '%s\n' "${#both[@]} .txt file${both[2]+s} in $dir have matching files with the same root name and a .ctl extension"
  printf '%s\n' "$dir has ${#txt_but_not_ctl[@]} .txt file${txt_but_not_ctl[2]+s} without a corresponding .ctl file"
  printf '%s\n' "$dir has ${#ctl_but_not_txt[@]} .ctl file${ctl_but_not_txt[2]+s} without a corresponding .txt file"

  ((${#both[@]} && ${#txt_but_not_ctl[@]} == 0 && ${#ctl_but_not_txt[@]} == 0)) &&
    printf '%s\n' "all the .txt files in $dir have a corresponding .ctl file and vis versa"
done
```

Where:

- `N` and `D` are replaced with the global `nullglob` and `dotglob` options.
- `:t` with the `"${array[@]##*/}"` pattern-stripping ksh operator
- `:r` with the `"${array[@]%*/}"` pattern-stripping ksh operator
- array union and subtraction is performed using `sort` + `comm` on NUL-delimited records and in the C locale (NUL being the only byte that  can't be found in a file name (or in bash variables as it happens)).